# arm disassembly - ADR or SUB?

Tags: arm, qemu, disassembly, ida

I started to build a arm disassembler.
I have the binary "48 00 4F E2"

Ida:

> ROM:00000040 48 00 4F E2                 ADR             R0, sub_0

Qemu:

> e24f0048      sub  r0, pc, #72

I do not think it's an BE/LE problem because the commands that came before and after would look the same.

What happens ?

Comment: `adr` and `sub` can be the same instruction.  `adr` is a pseudo-op.  IDA tries to be smarter and looks at  `add/sub Rn, pc, #offset` and says, this looks like a constant load so I will show `adr`.

Answer (score 0):

so if you just try it...

```
.word 0x48004FE2
.word 0xe24f0048
```

gives

```
   0:   48004fe2    stmdami r0, {r1, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, r10, r11, lr}
   4:   e24f0048    sub r0, pc, #72 ; 0x48
```

but since you are writing a disassembler (very good exercise to learn an instruction set BTW, keep going)...the first thing you notice is the condition code.  Neither of the results you saw have "mi" associated with it so neither assuming they are both disassembling arm and arm mode, did not see that 4 as the top nibble.  the 0xe is ALways so not noted.

you also see in your arm documentation that adr starts with

cccc0010010x1111 or cccc0010100x1111  0xX24F 0xX28F

and it is a sub without the Rn being 1111, but one disassembler chose to honor ADR which is a pseudo instruction, the other just decoded it as a sub.  It may also matter what architecture you specified.  In the newer arm arm ADR shows that it is supported by armv4t on, but the older arm arm (armv4 and armv5 and some armv6) shows no ADR instruction.  It just shows the sub.

which starts as 
cccc00I0010SNNNN

where cccc is the condition code I can be a zero in some cases or a 1 in this case, S is the save flags or not and NNNN is Rn.

sub(cond)(s) Rd,Rn,shifter operand

you have 0xE24F  so that is

sub r0,pc,shifter_operand.

I is a 1 so that is a 32 bit immediate.  0x48 with a rotate of 0x0  which is a decimal 72 (hex 0x48).

what is at 0x40-0x48+8 (address 0x0000)?  is that the label sub_0?

It is looking like they both correctly disassembled the instruction.

If you are truly making a disassembler though then you shouldnt have needed to ask this question as you had everything you needed in front of you already.

Comment: when pondering a question like this if the arm instruction wasnt obvious as it is in this case or if just curious you could have examined the 0x4800 or 0x4FE2 in thumb mode to see if one was disassembling that, but a quick check there and you find those dont line up with ADR in thumb mode.